# CellClass with function does not work (ng-grid)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

If I write, like the following

```
{ field: 'NumberOfDaysSinceFailure', displayName: 'Days on Watchlist',
        cellClass: function (grid, row, col, rowRenderIndex, colRenderIndex) {
            return 'green';
            }
        }
```

it does not work

However, If I write like

```
{ field: 'NumberOfDaysSinceFailure', displayName: 'Days on Watchlist',
            cellClass: 'green'

            }
```

It works as I want it to. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you read the documentation  - cellClass appends a string (class) so wherever it is appending it is not going to evaluate your function. I don't know enough about what you are trying to do by using that function to suggest something.

Comment: you could try `cellTemplate` inside that use html element with `ng-class` like `<span ng-class="myFunction(grid, row, col, rowRenderIndex, colRenderIndex)"><span>` & then myFunction would be there inside scope

Answer (score 0):

use cellTemplate

cellClass wont be applied if latest styles for particular overide